# Example of threadLocal from Java Doc is right?

Tags: java, thread-local

[Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

```
 public class UniqueThreadIdGenerator {

     private static final AtomicInteger uniqueId = new AtomicInteger(0);

     private static final ThreadLocal < Integer > uniqueNum = 
         new ThreadLocal < Integer > () {
             @Override protected Integer initialValue() {
                 return uniqueId.getAndIncrement();
         }
     };
 
     public static int getCurrentThreadId() {
         // uniqueId is right? or is uniqueNum ?
         return uniqueId.get();
     }
 } // UniqueThreadIdGenerator
```

getCurrentThreadId() uniqueId is right？I think uniqueNum is right

learn from each other about Threadlocal~~

Comment: You want `uniqueNum.get()`. `uniqueId.get()` will just give you the next ID.

Comment: Oh, I see, it's a mistake in the JavaDoc. Looks like it was corrected in [Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).

Comment: @shmosel thank you, If you'd like to add it as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.